# How to popup a menu bar using a short-cut?

Tags: macos, cocoa

If someone is using a browser, or any other application, I want the user to be able to type in a short cut (control-shift-P for example), and then I want my menu bar to popup a window so the user can enter some text, hit enter to close.

How can I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found a solution already but here's my answer for this question.

What you may be searching is a global hotkey. Check out this tutorial on how to create a global hotkey: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.ch/2009/03/global-keyboard-shortcuts-with-carbon.html

Once you got that part working the only thing you need to do is open your Window.
You can do this via the following:

```
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

Hope this helped anyone who is still searching for an answer